# Firebase init error in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, firebase, google-cloud-endpoints

I am now developing a java Google cloud endpoint in GAE. Inside the endpoint it will try to connect to the Firebase server to get some data.

However, when I create the Firebase object in my endpoint,

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase(<My Firebase URL>);
```

GAE throws the following error:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup") 
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:382) 
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:572) 
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549) 
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.checkAccess(ThreadGroup.java:315) 
    at java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:391) 
    at java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:349) 
    at java.lang.Thread.<init>(Thread.java:675) 
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DefaultThreadFactory.newThread(Executors.java:572) 
    at com.firebase.client.utilities.DefaultRunLoop$FirebaseThreadFactory.newThread(DefaultRunLoop.java:25) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.<init>(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:600) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:943) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.ensurePrestart(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1635) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:307) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:526) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) 
    at com.firebase.client.utilities.DefaultRunLoop.scheduleNow(DefaultRunLoop.java:57) 
    at com.firebase.client.core.Repo.scheduleNow(Repo.java:176) 
    at com.firebase.client.core.Repo.<init>(Repo.java:58) 
    at com.firebase.client.core.RepoManager.getLocalRepo(RepoManager.java:46) 
    at com.firebase.client.core.RepoManager.getRepo(RepoManager.java:19) 
    at com.firebase.client.Firebase.<init>(Firebase.java:194) 
    at com.firebase.client.Firebase.<init>(Firebase.java:199) 
    at com.firebase.client.Firebase.<init>(Firebase.java:177)
```

I am using Firebase client 2.2.3. It seems like GAE does not allow an application to create new threads. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ Mario is correct, App Engine app may not spawn new threads according to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/java#threads).This is because the AppEngine application run in the sandbox environment in which you have some restrictions.If still you want to develop your app without out any restriction then I would suggest try [Managed VM](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/) in which you don't have these types of restrictions.

Comment: You can actually run threads using basic or manual scaling without going through all the hassle of setting a managed VM, the only restriction is on automatic scaling: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/#Java_Background_threads

Answer (score 4):

In the Java runtime for Google App Engine there are some restrictions on creating new threads.

Please see [the Threads section](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/#Java_The_sandbox) for details.

Answer (score -3):

I think [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/server/start) link will help you, it describes how we can use firebase realtime database from server application using service account.

You can use following code snippet to connect to firebase database .

```
// Initialize the app with a service account, granting admin privileges
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
    .setDatabaseUrl("https://databaseName.firebaseio.com")
    .setServiceAccount(new FileInputStream("path/to/serviceAccountCredentials.json"))
    .build();
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

// As an admin, the app has access to read and write all data, regardless of Security Rules
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase
    .getInstance()
    .getReference("restricted_access/secret_document");
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Object document = dataSnapshot.getValue();
        System.out.println(document);
    }
});
```

Comment: This does nothing to address the stated question. The above code will fail in exactly the same way as the original post.

Comment: Hi @AaronSarazan, I tested it before posting and was working, if you are facing any error please post that here.